# Rails sending mails with actionmailer from an virtualbox vm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, debian, virtualbox, actionmailer

I have an Debian VM running in Virtual box on my Windows machine.

In my VM is a Rails application running, which should send mails with the action mailer.

I've set up the action mailer credentials in application.rb

But when a mail should be send there is nothing in my mailbox ... It seems like the mail isn't send or dosn't leve the vm.

What could I do to check if the mail is send properly?

Comment: Could you please put some more information like your code, as it is nothing to take with VM?

Comment: what environment type are you using? what smtp, local or remote?

Comment: Which code do you want to see? environement is development at the moment. SMTP is from 1und1.de -> ping and telnet to the smtp works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development environment you need these options in environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

By default rails in development mode only shows email body in log without real sending.

Comment: I've done this, but nothing changed, The Mail is printed in log but not sended ... I think. It's nothing in my mailbox. How can I check if the mail is send?

Comment: didn't you forget to restart server after making changes in config directory ?

Comment: restartet the server about 1000 times :(

Comment: Do I have to had a postfix server in the virtual machine?